# Correct way to use copy Postgres jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-copy

Unable to use copy command with jdbc Postgres. Whats wrong with the below code snippet sample.

```
public boolean loadReportToDB(String date) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Connection connection = DBUtil.getConnection("POSTGRESS");
        String fileName = "C:/_0STUFF/NSE_DATA/nseoi_" + date + ".csv";
        String sql = "\\copy fno_oi FROM 'C:\\_0STUFF\\NSE_DATA\\nseoi_27102017.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV header";
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            System.out.println("query"+ps.toString());
            int rowsaffected = ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("INT+" + rowsaffected);
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
  Position: 1
    at org.
```

if we use

```
String sql = "copy fno_oi FROM 'C:\\_0STUFF\\NSE_DATA\\nseoi_27102017.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV header";
```

then no rows are updated

postgres version postgresql-10.0-1-windows-x64

Comment: You don't need the \\ in from of the copy statement. And what's the error you're getting?

Comment: Does the file `C:\\_0STUFF\\NSE_DATA\\nseoi_27102017.csv` exist on the server? And does it get loaded if you test the statement manually?

Comment: postgres-# \copy fno_oi FROM 'C:\_0STUFF\NSE_DATA\nseoi_27102017.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV header
COPY 212

Comment: the same command works from sql shell.

Comment: `\copy` is a `psql` command **not** a [SQL command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) you need to use `copy` instead: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html or use the CopyManager API: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
String sql = "copy fno_oi FROM 'C:/_0STUFF/NSE_DATA/nseoi_27102017.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV header";
  try {
   CopyManager copyManager = new CopyManager((BaseConnection)connection);
   copyManager.copyIn(sql);
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
the above command works but throws an exception.Seems like problem with jdbc driver 
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/D960CB61B694CF459DCFB4B0128514C20393819B@exadv11.host.magwien.gv.at
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Received CommandComplete

Answer (score 23):

This works for me:

```java
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connUrl, myUid, myPwd)) {
    long rowsInserted = new CopyManager((BaseConnection) conn)
            .copyIn(
                "COPY table1 FROM STDIN (FORMAT csv, HEADER)", 
                new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/gord/Desktop/testdata.csv"))
                );
    System.out.printf("%d row(s) inserted%n", rowsInserted);
}
```

Using `copyIn(String sql, Reader from)` has the advantage of avoiding issues where the PostgreSQL server process is unable to read the file directly, either because it lacks permissions (like reading files on my Desktop) or because the file is not local to the machine where the PostgreSQL server is running.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved the day Gord, the `CopyManager` is what I was looking to work with STDIN

Answer (score 5):

As your input file is stored *locally* on the computer running your Java program you need to use the equivalent of `copy ... from stdin` in JDBC because `copy` can only access files on the **server** (where Postgres is running).

To do that use the `CopyManager` API provided by the JDBC driver.

Something along the lines:

```
Connection connection = DBUtil.getConnection("POSTGRES");

String fileName = "C:/_0STUFF/NSE_DATA/nseoi_" + date + ".csv";
String sql = "copy fno_oi FROM stdin DELIMITER ',' CSV header";

BaseConnection pgcon = (BaseConnection)conection;
CopyManager mgr = new CopyManager(pgcon);

try {

  Reader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
  long rowsaffected  = mgr.copyIn(sql, in);

  System.out.println("Rows copied: " + rowsaffected);

} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what's the recommended way if postgress server and application server are different

Comment: @MrinalBhattacharjee `CopyManager`