# How can I create a COPYfunction with myBatis mapper in the xml file?

Tags: java, postgresql, copy, mybatis

How Can I create a COPY function in the .xml mapper with myBatis?
And what values this function will return?
I think it is as

```
<copy id="copyFunction">
    COPY (SELECT * FROM #{table_name} WHERE backup = 1) TO 'C:\var\audiobays\logs\audit\' || #{table_name} || '_deletions_(' || now()::DATE || '-' || days || ').csv'' CSV DELIMITER '','' HEADER;'
</copy>
```

But I'm not sure that it is what.
Can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't as mybatis does not implement support for `copy`.

`COPY` is postgresql specific command and it is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958965/how-to-copy-a-data-from-file-to-postgresql-using-jdbc) [supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988855/correct-way-to-use-copy-postgres-jdbc) in JDBC. To use it postgresql specific classes like `CopyManager` are needed.

mybatis uses JDBC to access database and does not provide support for non standard features like this.

Comment: Can do you take mi a mini-example? Thank's

Comment: Ok, I didn' t see the link. Thank you!