# How to form correct CSV line with postgres SQL

Tags: csv

Is it possible to query Postgresql in order to get correct CSV line? For instance `select concat (a,',',b) from t` but with correctly escaped commas and quotes.

Comment: 1) What version of Postgres? 2) What client are you using?

Comment: Version is 14.1. Client is self-written java app via jdbc connection.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options.

Using [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

```
select * from some_table \g (format=csv) output.csv
```

This will create a CSV file named `output.csv`.

```
\copy cell_per to 'output.csv' WITH(format csv, header, delimiter '|');
```

The above allows you to use the options as explained here [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) to do things like change the `delimiter`, `quoting`, etc.

You can also use `COPY` directly as a query. Though in that case it is important to note that `COPY` runs as the server user and can only write files to directories the server user has permissions on. The work around is to make the output go to `STDOUT` and and capture it. For instance using the Python driver `psycopg2` there are `copy` methods [copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from).

Comment: Sorry it was worth to note that psql wasn't an option. Client is self written. I need an sql statement probably with postgres specific function to get properly formed CSV.

Comment: There is a Postgres specific statement to output CSV it is `COPY` as mentioned in the answer. If you are using the Postgres community JDBC driver then maybe this [JDBC Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988855/correct-way-to-use-copy-postgres-jdbc)?